# How to force a screen resolution on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, resolution

I have a MacBook Pro, bought 3 years ago, I'm not sure of the model, but the processor is a 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, with 4 GB of RAM, nVidia 9400M 256M. I am using MacOS 10.6.6.

Next week I will do a presentation in a conference, and they suggest to use a `1280 x 720` resolution, as the conference will be recorded using the `16:9` format.

Unfortunately, when I want to change the resolution of my screen on my laptop (`System preferences > Displays > Screen resolutions`), it does not provide this resolution. I can use `1024 x 768` which is the "backup" resolution for the conference, but not the suggested resolution.

So my question: is there a way to force such resolution on my MBP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you connect it to a display that offers 1280 x 720 as a resolution, then it should give you that as an option. You need to test it with the display that you will be using at the conference, which is always a good idea.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand well, even if my MBP can't display (or at least does not provide) `1280x720` on the laptop screen, it will be able to *output* such resolution?

Comment: Correct. As Mike says when you connect to another display or projector the computer will offer different resolutions for you to choose from when that display is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

edit 
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist
add these lines, save & reboot.

```
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1280x720x32</string>
```

to edit com.apple.boot.plist you may have to copy it to your desktop first, edit it and then put it back to where it was, overwriting the original file